# How do I farm cursed chests?

Tags: diablo-iii

Are there any requisites for them to spawn?

Where do I find cursed chests?

This are chests that are supposed to give big rewards after beating a group of elites.

Comment: I believe the intent is that you won't know a chest is cursed until you open it. That being said I haven't found one yet.

Comment: there's a particular cursed chest run right now that's the main target for farming, averaging about 1b xp per hour

Comment: .... and now its been patched :P

Comment: Got a link or 'blue comment'?

Answer (score 4):

Cursed chests do look different then regular chests. They kind of look like the demonic versions of the big golden 'Resplendent' chests.

Here's a picture of one: [image: Cursed Chest]

Apparently, however, many of these chests spawn in predetermined positions across all acts.
See http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9887928799 for details.

That being said, see [this blue post](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/11884298579?page=1#1) that says: 'Cursed chests are similar to other events. They have some degree of randomness, such as where exactly in a dungeon they spawn (if they spawn at all)'

Comment: The first link no longer works.  A similar list seems to be at http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/topic/9887928799 -- maybe edit the content from it into this answer?

Comment: @Brythan Thanks for letting me know. I've edited in your link.