# How Do Cursed Chests Work?

Tags: diablo-iii

With the new 2.0 update, Blizzard introduced Cursed Chests into Diablo 3. I don't really understand how they work. When I opened the cursed chest I found it triggered an event. A timer started and I was told that if I kill 100 enemies I get some kind of additional prize. I started slashing my way through enemies. I didn't make it to 100 but I did make it to around 50. After the timer expired, a message popped up on my screen that said, "You killed 0 enemies before the timer ran out."

Umm, no I didn't. I saw where I had killed at least 50 enemies. Is this a bug or am I not understanding how these things work? Do I have to get to 100 monsters for it to count at all? What happens if I do hit 100 monsters? I just need to know everything about cursed chests.

Comment: related or dupe? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/157974/how-do-i-farm-cursed-chests

Comment: and the 0 enemies thing is definitely a glitch.  If you do succeed the event you will get a second chest.

Comment: @z- I don't think it's a dupe. I'm not interested in their locations or farming them, I just want to know what happens when I trigger the event and what the different outcomes are (under 100 monsters versus 100 monsters).

Comment: I can answer the cursed chest part, but I haven'et come across a cursed shrine yet.  All I know is you have to kill 5 waves within a timer, but I don't know the reward.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update for ROS:

There is a new type of cursed chest, that doesn't cause a major 'cursed chest event' and are mostly encountered in Adventure Mode.

These new cursed chests are basically resplendent chests that are 'locked' until the curse is lifted.  When activated, they can do 1 of the following (possibly more).

- Spawn a champion pack that you have to take down in a limited time (typically 30 seconds).
- Spawn a hoard of monsters that you have to kill in a limited time.
- Survive for X Time/# of waves (Thanks Doc)
- Spawn an act boss i.e. Skeleton King.

The major cursed chests still operates as follows:

- When you find a cursed chest, you will begin an event.  The goal of the event is to reach 100 kills before the timer runs out.
- As soon as you open the chest, enemies will begin to spawn around the chest, starting out slowly but eventually reaching swarming levels.
- If you die, you can respawn but the timer will not stop during this period.
- At the end of the event, it will tell you how many monsters you have killed before the timer runs out.  *Monsters killed after the timer has stopped do not count.*  But you have to kill them to 'complete' the event to get the chests to spawn.
- If you do succeed in killing 100 monsters before the timer runs out, a second chest will spawn.  Each has a pretty high chance to drop 1 rare or better (this is with almost no MF).

Comment: Not sure if the cursed chests have changed or not.  I've never experienced the spawn of an act boss - are those Adventure Mode only?  I've also seen some "survive for x-time/waves" events.

Comment: @Doc yes they could be in adventure mode only. I've been doing a lot of those lately.  And its also quite rare.

Comment: Found a boss event, it was Ghom, from Act 3, who appeared.

Comment: The last update to this answer seems to imply you can only find cursed chests in adventure mode, but that's not the case.  The "kill 100 enemies" and "kill 5 waves" can spawn in story mode (I believe from cursed chests and cursed shrines respectively), but the simpler "kill all in 30s" I've only seen from chests in adventure mode. Never seen a boss event so can't comment.